# If $P$ is perfect and $K $ is compact then what can we say that $P\bigcup K$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

If $P$ is perfect and $K $ is compact then what can we sat that $P\bigcup K$

Set $P$ is perfect $\rightarrow$ closed and contains no isolated points

Set $K$ is compact $\rightarrow$ closed and bounded

I know that $P\bigcap K$ is compact.

Comment: If you say that "Set K is compact → closed and bounded" you are assuming things about the topology. I guess that $P$ and $K$ must be subsets of  ... what?

Comment: @ajotatxe.. as i know a compact set is closed and bounded

Comment: @ajotatxe..sorry if i am wrong

Comment: @Psuresh Compact sets are closed and bounded in $\mathbb R^n$, but this is not true in general

Answer (score 1):

We can only say $P\cup K$ is closed.

$P\cup K$ may not be compact as $P=\Bbb{R}$ is a counter example.

$P\cup K$ may not be perfect either as any $K$ that $K-P$ is not perfect is counter example.

Answer (score 0):

Union of two closed sets is closed.

Comment: ..is that compact

Comment: Not if $P$ isn't.